# Where is the ViewResult returned by ASP.NET Core Controller consumed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the definition of the ASP.NET Core [`Controller` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller?view=aspnetcore-5.0), it defines the [`View()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Controller_View) as returning a [`ViewResult` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
{
     //...
    public abstract class Controller : ControllerBase, IActionFilter, IFilterMetadata, IAsyncActionFilter, IDisposable
    {
     //...   
        public virtual ViewResult View();
     //...
    }
}
```

Where is it in the framework that invokes a controller method such as below and consumes the `ViewResult` returned by the call to the `View()` method?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this because you are interested, or is their something you are trying to do that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

The entire process is quite involved, and is managed internally by the [`ResourceInvoker` class](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ResourceInvoker.cs), but the main piece of plumbing responsible for handling a `ViewResult` is the [`ViewExecutor` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.viewexecutor?view=aspnetcore-5.0) ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/ViewResultExecutor.cs)).

The primary entry point of the `ViewExecutor` is the [`ExecuteAsync()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.viewexecutor.executeasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewFeatures_ViewExecutor_ExecuteAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewEngines_IView_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewFeatures_ViewDataDictionary_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewFeatures_ITempDataDictionary_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Int32__), which accepts the [`ActionContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and your `ViewResult`. It then locates the appropriate view using the registered [`IViewEngine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewengines.iviewengine?view=aspnetcore-5.0) (typically the [`RazorViewEngine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorviewengine?view=aspnetcore-5.0)) to identify the corresponding view and return a [`ViewEngineResult` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewengines.viewengineresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0). That `ViewEngineResult` is then used to execute and render the view.

#### Extending `ViewExecutor`

If you need to customize the logic, you can implement your own view executor class by implementing the [`IActionResultExecutor<>` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.iactionresultexecutor-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and then registering it as a singleton using ASP.NET Core's dependency injection container. When doing so, I recommend referencing [the out-of-the-box `ViewResultExecutor`'s source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/ViewResultExecutor.cs).

This can be useful if you want to implement custom logic for locating the view. For instance, perhaps you want to account for state or context data such as route data, request headers, cookies, session, &c. when locating the view.

So, as a really simple example, let us say you want to allow a view to be optionally selected using a query string value (e.g., `?View=MyView`). In that case, you might create a `QueryStringViewResultExecutor`. Here's a basic proof-of-concept:

```cs
public class QueryStringViewResultExecutor : ViewExecutor, IActionResultExecutor<ViewResult> 
{
    public QueryStringViewResultExecutor(
        IOptions<MvcViewOptions> viewOptions,
        IHttpResponseStreamWriterFactory writerFactory,
        ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine,
        ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataFactory,
        DiagnosticListener diagnosticListener,
        IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider
    ) : base(
        viewOptions, writerFactory, viewEngine, tempDataFactory, diagnosticListener, modelMetadataProvider
    ) 
    {
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result) 
    {
        var viewEngineResult = FindView(context, result); // See helper method below
        viewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(originalLocations: null);
        var view = viewEngineResult.View;

        using (view as IDisposable) 
        {
            await ExecuteAsync(
                context,
                view,
                result.ViewData,
                result.TempData,
                result.ViewName,
                result.StatusCode
            ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    private ViewEngineResult FindView(ActionContext actionContext, ViewResult viewResult) 
    {

        // Define variables
        var view = (ViewEngineResult?)null;
        var viewEngine = viewResult.ViewEngine?? ViewEngine;
        var searchedPaths = new List<string>();
        var requestContext = actionContext.HttpContext.Request;

        // If defined, attempt to locate view based on query string variable
        if (requestContext.Query.ContainsKey("View")) 
        {
            var queryStringValue = requestContext.Query["View"].First<string>();
            if (queryStringValue is not null) 
            {
                view = viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, queryStringValue, isMainPage: true);
                searchedPaths = searchedPaths.Union(view.SearchedLocations?? Array.Empty<string>()).ToList();
            }
        }

        // If no view is found, fall back to the view defined on the viewResult
        if (!view?.Success?? true) 
        {
            view = viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewResult.ViewName, isMainPage: true);
            searchedPaths = searchedPaths.Union(view.SearchedLocations ?? Array.Empty<string>()).ToList();
        }

        // Return view for processing by the razor engine
        if (view is not null and { Success: true }) {
            return view;
        }
        return ViewEngineResult.NotFound(viewResult.ViewName, searchedPaths);

    }
}
```

You would then register this in your `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method as:

```cs
services.Services.TryAddSingleton<IActionResultExecutor<ViewResult>, QueryStringViewResultExecutor>();
```

> *Disclaimer:* You may need to unregister the out-of-the-box `ViewExecutor` in order to avoid a conflict. Typically, however, you are registering an `IActionResultExecutor<>` with a custom `ViewResult` and, thus, that isn't necessary; see below.

#### Extending `ViewResult`

Often, you will want to pair this with a custom `ViewResult`. Why is this useful? Usually because you need to pass additional data to your `ViewResultExecutor` from your `Controller`.

So, as a contrived example, imagine that you have themes, and views can optionally be customized based on that theme. You might then add a `Theme` property to your `ViewResult`, thus allowing the `ViewResultExecutor` to first look for a view based on the theme, and otherwise fallback to the non-themed version.

```cs
public class ThemedViewResult : ViewResult 
{

    public string Theme { get; set; }

    public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context) 
    {
        var executor = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IActionResultExecutor<ThemedViewResult>>();
        await executor.ExecuteAsync(context, this).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Even if you don't need a custom `ViewResult`, it's worth pausing for a second to evaluate this code. The underlying `ViewResult` class implements [`IActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0), which exposes a single method, [`ExecuteResultAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult.executeresultasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0). This is called by the `ResourceInvoker` class mentioned at the top. This in turn locates the registered `IActionResultExecutor<>`—i.e., the type of component we created and registered in the previous section—and calls its `ExecuteAsync()` method.

> *Note:* This is a contrived example because often a theme would be accessible by other context data, such as the `RouteData`, a custom `ClaimsPrincipal`, or an `ISession` implementation. But you can imagine other times where this information would be request-specific, and best relayed from the `Controller` via the `ViewResult`. For instance, perhaps a CMS where the theme can be selected on a per page basis.

As it's unclear whether you actually need to extend this functionality or are just curious how everything fits together, the above examples are only meant as a proof-of-concept; they aren't tested. Still, they should give you a basic idea of where and how the `ViewResult` is handled, as well as options for extending that behavior should you need.

Comment: I've expanded on my explanation of the `ViewResult`'s implementation of `IActionResult`, which is called from the `ResourceInvoker`, and is responsible for calling the `ExecuteAsync()` method on the `ViewExecutor`. That helps clarify the relationship between these three components, and how they interact with one another. This is otherwise confusing since the `ViewExecutor` isn't called directly from the `ResourceInvoker`.